# pip install dubins gives multiple errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-c++, pip

I was trying to install the dubins plugin using the terminal in python and I keep getting this error.

Things I have tried

- My python Version is 3.9.0 and it is for Windows 10 x64
- My setuptools has been upgraded
- I tried downloading the tar.gz file but that gave me the same error.

Trying to install dubins earlier gave me this error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. I installed Visual C++ 2019 and the Windows 10 SDK and then this is the issue I am getting.

````
   command: 'c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ranai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\\dubins\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ranai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\\dubins\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel 
-d 'C:\Users\ranai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-fghrj2kf'
       cwd: C:\Users\ranai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\dubins\
  Complete output (18 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'dubins' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\dubins
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\dubins\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Idubins/include -Ic:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcdubins/dubins.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\dubins/dubins.obj
  dubins.c
  dubins/dubins.c(4221): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
  c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
  dubins/dubins.c(4226): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
  c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
  dubins/dubins.c(4819): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  dubins/dubins.c(4835): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 
2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dubins
  Running setup.py clean for dubins
Failed to build dubins
Installing collected packages: dubins
    Running setup.py install for dubins ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ranai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\\dubins\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ranai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\\dubins\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ranai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9tcr8er0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\dubins'
         cwd: C:\Users\ranai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\dubins\
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'dubins' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\dubins
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\dubins\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Idubins/include -Ic:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcdubins/dubins.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\dubins/dubins.obj
    dubins.c
    dubins/dubins.c(4221): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    dubins/dubins.c(4226): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
    c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include\cpython/object.h(193): note: see declaration of '_typeobject'
    dubins/dubins.c(4819): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    dubins/dubins.c(4835): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ranai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\\dubins\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ranai\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6dvm2sbg\\dubins\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ranai\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9tcr8er0\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\ranai\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\dubins' Check the logs for full command output. ```
````

Comment: Did you install build tools for MS Studio 2019?

Comment: @pavel Yes I did. What build tools specifically are you referring to? I installed all the C++ ones

Comment: Error `'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'` means that the code is intended for a different version of Python. [The home page](https://pypi.org/project/dubins/) suggests it's for  Python, 2.7 and 3.4-3.6. The `tp_print` method was removed from the API in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who finds this at a future time, my biggest problem was I was trying to run Linux code on Windows. I switched to Linux and everything started working instantly. That's all I got for you.